# What git repository do the mainline kernel ppa builds come from, and are any changes made?

Tags: kernel, mainline-kernel

I am debugging a curious issue with the kernel not supporting my laptop completely. 
([This is my bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/903558))

I have installed the mainline builds from the mainline kernel ppa (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), and discovered that the last working kernel version is v3.2.1. Anything after it, i.e. v3.2.2, breaks. So I was going to use the *git bisect* tool to identity the specific commit between v3.2.1 and v3.2.2 which breaks on my laptop.

I followed [the instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) but the git repo they link to doesn't have the tags for v3.2.x, so I found another one which sounds official and has the right tags: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=summary, but after building v3.2.1 I still had the issue.

So, what git repo do the mainline kernels come from?
Also, are any patches/changes applied to them after being retrieved from the repository which wouldn't be in my build?

Answer (score 2):

The mainline builds are built from the official upstream repositories (linus's tree and gregkh's stable tree for instance).  Where the build claims to be against a tag it is the official tag from that version.  You can confirm you have the right one using the file `COMMIT` in the same directory as the binary .debs, this lists the SHA1 or tag which was used as a base for the build, all patches applied to the tree are in the same directory.